# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sample'

Tags: python

I'm getting `AttributeError`: `'module' object has no attribute 'sample'` while running below lines of code:
It would be great if anybody could figure me out where the main errors comes from.

[image]

```
## importing modules
import random
import math

## storing strings in a list
digits = [i for i in range(0, 10)]

## initializing a string
random_str = ""

## we can generate any lenght of string we want
for i in range(6):
    index = math.floor(random.random() * 10)
    random_str += str(digits[index])

print(random_str)
```

Comment: You have a file called `random.py` which shadows the standard libary module `random`

Comment: 1. as @IsmailBadawi mentioned that can be one of the cases where you have a file named random in the api folder.
2. Please check the version of the python and see if you can run python in console or terminal and see if you can import random sucessfully

Comment: there have no `random.py` file in my project.

Comment: You have named your own module, which is a library name of python

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an import issue. Is there another module in the same directory named random(.py)? If so, you need to (re)move this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reload` to solve this `module` problem

```
import the_module_name
from importlib import reload
reload(the_module_name)
```